# How to create a type for a comma delimited string of arbitrary item count

Tags: typescript, types

I have an object of filter values:

```
const values = {
  search,
  users,
  categories,
  sorting,
}
```

From this I want to derive a type called FilterSelection that extends strings. Here are some
examples of valid and invalid FilterSelections:

```
exampleFilterSelections = {
  valid: [
    "all",
    "search,users,sorting",
    "-search",
    "-search,-users",
  ], 
  invalid: [
    "any",
    "search,-users",
    "users,users",
    "accounts",
  ]
}
```

Its trivial to get individual options:

```
type IncludedFilter = keyof typeof values
type ExcludedFilter = `-${SelectedFilter}`
```

Then if I can define `FilterInclussions` and `FilterExclusions`, I can simply combine them

```
type FilterSelection = FilterInclusions | FilterExclusions | "all"
```

However I'm not sure how to define either of these types.

```
type FilterInclusions = 
  | IncludedFilter 
  | `${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter}`
  | `${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter}`
  | `${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter}`
  | `${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter}`
  | `${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter},${IncludedFilter}`
  // etc...
```

But this seems wordy. Is there a better less manual way to do this?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve, what is the rule behind valid and invalid filter strings? `values` is also not valid typescript, since the values (search, users, ...) aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/ND89RN) what you're looking for? This sort of thing doesn't scale very well so if `values` has more than six or seven keys in it you'll be sad... hopefully your list of four is representative of the actual size of the use case.  If it works for you I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz You actually handled an invalid case that I had not thought of (same key twice, I'll add it to the question). I really would appreciate it if you explained your answer a bit. I'm not even sure what `[U] extends [T]` means. That being said I think I will be sad as I was hoping to have an indefinate amount of filters, quite possibly more than 7. I would be surprised there isn't a more performant way to do this having seen some of the things arktype can do.

Comment: So does it meet your needs or not?  If you've got many filters then no specific type will work (since it would have to be a union holding more than the maximum of 100K members) and you'd need to refactor from `const x: FilterSelection = "foo,bar"` to a generic helper function like `const x = filterSelection("foo,bar")`.  If you want to pursue that method I can work it up and show you what it would look like, but I'm not going to do both answers or my answer will go from probably-too-long-already to unfathomably-gargantuan.  So which way do you want to go?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help. Secondly I'm not sure I undestand what you mean by a generic helper function. It might be what I am looking for, the type hint is meant for the parameter of a function but I'm not sure how that would reduce the number of permutations

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w22yrw).  It reduces the work by just checking your input for validity instead of enumerating every possible permutation in advance.  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: The second one does exactly what I need. I suppose I should make the question a bit clearer.

Comment: Okay then I'll write up an answer for the second version when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's unfortunately no scalable way to write a specific `FilterSelection` type in TypeScript. You'd need to write it as an explicit [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)
of every allowable string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html), because there's no specific type that abstracts over your desired rules.  (TypeScript lacks *regular-expression-validated string types* as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160), and *pattern template literals* as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598) only allow patterns like "any string" or "any numeric string" or even "any uppercase string".)  Union types can only hold up to about 100,000 members, so if your union is larger than that you'll have a bad time.  Since the list of all possible permutations of a set of strings grows [super-exponentially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) in the size of the set, you'll quickly run into the limit for just a handful of input strings.

So we're giving up on a specific type for `FilterSelection`.

---

The best we can do is write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type like `ValidateFilterSelection<T>` that acts like a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `T`, so that `T extends ValidateFilterSelection<T>` if and only if `T` is a valid filter selection.  And then we can make a generic helper function like

```
const filterSelection = <T extends string>(
  t: ValidateFilterSelection<T>
) => t as T;
```

So that you can have the compiler infer `T` instead of requiring that you write it out manually.  So instead of `const f: FilterSelection = "categories,users"`, you'd write `const f = filterSelection("categories,users")` which looks the same if you squint at it right.  So the hope is that it would behave like this:

```
const f = filterSelection("categories,users"); // okay

const g = filterSelection("categories,-users"); // error
// ---------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"categories,-users"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type ....
```

And if you want to write an array of them you can make a helper function that [maps `ValidateFilterSeclection<T>` over a tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), so it behaves like:

```
const filterSelections = <T extends string[]>(
  t: [...{ [I in keyof T]: ValidateFilterSelection<T[I]> }]
) => t as T;
   
let exampleFilterSelections = filterSelections([
  "all", // okay
  "search,users,sorting", // okay
  "-search", // okay
  "-search,-users", // okay
  "search,categories,sorting,users" // okay
  "any", // error
  "search,-users", // error
  "accounts", // error
]);
```

So the question is: how do we write `ValidateFilterSelection<T>`?

---

Here's one approach:

```
type ValidateSelection<V extends string, T extends string, A extends string = ""> =
  T extends V ? `${A}${A extends "" ? "" : ","}${T}` :
  T extends `${infer F extends V},${infer R}` ? ValidateSelection<
    Exclude<V, F>, R, `${A}${A extends "" ? "" : ","}${F}`
  > : `${A}${A extends "" ? "" : ","}${V}`

type IncludedFilter = "search" | "users" | "categories" | "sorting"
type ExcludedFilter = `-${IncludedFilter}`

type ValidateFilterSelection<T extends string> =
  ValidateSelection<IncludedFilter, T> |
  ValidateSelection<ExcludedFilter, T> |
  "all";
```

Let's talk about `ValidateSelection<V, T>`:

The type `ValidateSelection<V, T>` takes a union of valid string pieces `V`, and a candidate string type `T` and returns `T` if it's a valid joining of some of those pieces with commas.  If `T` is invalid, then it returns a valid version "close" to `T` in some sense, so that error messages are hopefully somewhat useful (i.e., "you wrote *that* but you should probably have written *this* instead.) So `ValidateSelection<"a"|"b"|"c", "a,b">` should be `"a,b"`, but `ValidateSelection<"a"|"b"|"c", "b,b">` should be something else, like `"b,a" | "b,c"`.

It's a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that splits `T` into pieces, can *accumulates* the result in the type parameter `A`; if `T` is already one of the valid `V` pieces, then we return `A` concatenated with `T`.  Otherwise if `T` starts `F` (a valid `V` piece) followed by a comma and `R` (the rest of the string), then we recurse into `ValidateSelection` with `Exclude<V, F>` as the new `V`, and with `R` as the new `T`, and with `A` concatenated with `F` as the new `A`.  And finally, if `T` does not start with a valid `V`, then we return `A` concatenated with `V`.  This last bit is what is responsible for the "close" result.  With `Validate<"a"|"b"|"c", "b,b">`, it recurses into `Validate<"a"|"c", "b", "b">`, and finally becomes `"b,a" | "b, c"`.

And then `ValidateFilterSelection<T>` is just the union of `ValidateSelection<IncludedFilter, T>`, `ValidateSelection<ExcludedFilter, T>`, and `"all"`, so `T extends ValidateFilterSelection<T>` if and only if either `T extends ValidateSelection<IncludedFilter, T>` for the include filters, or `T extends ValidateSelection<ExcludedFilter, T>` for the exclude filters, or `T extends "all"`.

---

Let's see how it works, although there's just one more change::

```
const filterSelection = <T extends string>(
  t: ValidateFilterSelection<T> & {} // <-- & {} here
) => t as T;

const filterSelections = <T extends string[]>(
  t: [...{ [I in keyof T]: ValidateFilterSelection<T[I]> & {} }]
) => t as T;
```

I added `& {}` which doesn't change the types, but it will cause the error message to expand into a union of string literals instead of talking about the `ValidateFilterSelection` name.

And testing:

```
const f = filterSelection("categories,users"); // okay
const g = filterSelection("categories,-users"); // error
// ---------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"categories,-users"' is not assignable
// to parameter of type '"-search" | "-users" | "-categories" | "-sorting" | 
// "all" | "categories,users" | "categories,search" | "categories,sorting"'      

let exampleFilterSelections = filterSelections([
  "all", // okay
  "search,users,sorting", // okay
  "-search", // okay
  "-search,-users", // okay
  "search,categories,sorting,users" // okay
  "any", // error
  // Type '"any"' is not assignable to type '"search" | "users" 
  // | "categories" | "sorting" | "-search" | "-users" | 
  // "-categories" | "-sorting" | "all"'.
  "search,-users", // error
  // Type '"search,-users"' is not assignable to type '"-search" | "-users" | "-categories"
  // | "-sorting" | "all" | "search,users" | "search,categories" |
  //  "search,sorting"'. Did you mean '"search,users"'?
  "accounts", // error
  // Type '"accounts"' is not assignable to type '"search" | "users" |
  // "categories" | "sorting" | "-search" | "-users" | 
  // "-categories" | "-sorting" | "all"'.
])
```

Looks good.  Valid strings are accepted and invalid ones are rejected, and the error messages make reasonable-ish suggestions (maybe `"search,-users"` shouldn't mention `"-sorting"`, but the `Did you mean '"search,users"'?` is nice).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=false&ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgYwDYFcAmE0DECWTgQBOUAvFAEQDOEAhoQgBblQA+FK1hlzb5CNBAOYB7QjgjdWFSqOA44g8gCgA9Cqnk0wxRv7AeFALbDh1A+QJIIANxyUcwuOf6GiNc7UJJhAIwjkAbiVQSCgAUQAPZHRMXHwiUigAAwBaABIAb3hojGw8AkIAXySlYPBoADUaJBw0AQgAZQgrBDlHAB4KqAgIgjg0SihKYDEFABooABVu3oh+weHRwQmAQRm+gaGR+UFE8nIAPlIlKCn1uc2ugH5kzJXCu-P5imYb-agALgox8geMyeKnxOZx6G0GSUy8gAZgksE9LoUxpC4DDiAAlQE3Ko1OoEJotNpwdrA06RHIQToTLAHCZoiYQjL3R6gi6Dd5vZhfcg-P5YYrAo5fBlMxnwtmvF6fb6-TIVfllULY2r1OIFfEQVoOInTFnPRY7I4kYFK3GNZoawntbKoXKqogTSZHFjG6rKvHmzUdMk22L5e1TJ3A8jVJCBUoqABUwJ1s2ewaQoagN2mH2jYqgJvq6s9ROtMTy8UIDqOyaBpxjYIzrtN2ct3vzdqLAaTZ1Tp3jibYmfdBK1VsQPoLBWLrBdOKzHrrUUHjeLQQjKiUCEcwygUL9hFrWsS7QrrK2SwOAApgcAvt2II2tx1HVAAGRQDKFJQASlIR2AUBog0mQSXK8-KFEnXQtrzgI8+HqEQxAkMYOCIbgXwCKA1CgYQAGsaBAf84FXXYyBAtVJy1CC9AgaDxEoMYUngrhyCQlD1CIQhRFUdQUg4ziuO4nijgAPwEwShOEoS2KgFZCEEFBXDgT9hCAkJoAAckgoRREo6jaO4JSoDsKA4GET9v3sQQ4BoHwrDE4BhCgMA6BoVwCjQhTyigFSUmoOhGHMGjOEkXgUjIiiJB8mRCDkBQDDEjtnCg9TYK02K1JgqjPPoJhdDilKxjCiLFB005CtKUpl1wwCNzAwYyF3dN9QUABtABdY9Ty+eqADpOoyKB6pgXS4CgdCIBAeSpka89qxVCriJvXrmvvR9CigQpGtfd8oCMn8-yUKxPx6BywCsK8Ztw4Dpt7Fcj3qoMQ25Ri0Mw7D2zSxg4L8nLZB2O7UIwrCgw8zxvImH7Hv+l6GE0vzvvUX6nukQGIaC+LUs+8ZEvu2GbrgEBoe6QgWMIYFUMmVyVJobHyB0vSDM2kyzIs6BrI20mqAR8x0aJ9ReCRlLzFyr6NABryMoC9G2E5ihAqyyjQtRnReFupT2qDcHIYQ3HmNY05iZZ1XfPVqnBhpr9KDp8yrA2mzFLc8ghfSnyxclnmZYlgL+cijRbo0VXHdZ4WxmdkLR219R4f9938vaqAABFaigEaUCgVxyZtn2oaUq4boQZcUFk7hgaY-GtfuknQjJ7PhFz4BtN0o3DJNs2Gct5my79+2NDFiXVPI5G+bl0K2cFx2u6l5KZcFiPzEV5XGpfJQgA)